# Can I move a conversation to chat before the 11 comments threshold?

Tags: support, comment, chat

I searched for an answer to this question before asking, but I couldn't find it (I admit I'm not very skilled in using the "search" function on the SE sites). I would like to move the comments for this question to chat:

[Using multiple exposures in regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292579/using-multiple-exposures-in-regression-model)

Of course I could just create a chat room, then post a new comment with the chat link. However, I was wondering if there was a more automatic way to do it.

Comment: `I could just create a chat room, then post a new comment with the chat link` - that's what I did once or twice when I needed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag the post for Moderator attention, with a request to move the comments to chat.